# Remove Line Breaks in a Text File

Tags: vb.net

I have created an XML file using streamWriter.. Now, i want to remove the line breaks in my XML file.. Is there a way to accomplish this task..?

here's my sample outout

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <!--Arbortext, Inc., 1988-2004, v.4002-->
   <!DOCTYPE primary.hierarchy SYSTEM "http://phoenix.roc.westgroup.com/dtd/pax.dtd">
```

Output should look like this

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!--Arbortext, Inc., 1988-2004, v.4002--><!DOCTYPE primary.hierarchy SYSTEM "http://phoenix.roc.westgroup.com/dtd/pax.dtd">
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, why do you want to remove the line breaks?

Comment: I was able to resolved my issue using this code.. 

  Dim strInputData As String = oFinalReader.ReadToEnd()

  Dim strOutputData As New StringBuilder()

  For i As Integer = 0 To strInputData.Length - 1
       If Not Char.IsControl(strInputData, i) Then
           'append current string value 
            strOutputData.Append(strInputData(i))
       End If
  Next

  oFinalWriter.Write(strOutputData)

Thanks for your comments and suggestions.. appreciate it.. 

link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `StreamWriter` you can consider using XmlWriter instead.  It has various settings to deal with formatting of XML output.

See [XmlWriterSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.aspx) for details

BTW. I assume that have you used `WriteLine` with your StreamWriter approach use `Write` instead.  That should get rid of your line breaks.

Comment: I was able to resolved my issue using this code.. 

  Dim strInputData As String = oFinalReader.ReadToEnd()

  Dim strOutputData As New StringBuilder()

  For i As Integer = 0 To strInputData.Length - 1
       If Not Char.IsControl(strInputData, i) Then
           'append current string value 
            strOutputData.Append(strInputData(i))
       End If
  Next

  oFinalWriter.Write(strOutputData)

Thanks for your comments and suggestions.. appreciate it.. 

link